# pass credentails to Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkinsfile written for my project which has number of stages, out of that, in one stage I need to clone my private git repo which needs creds to be passed in order to download the code. I am not getting any idea on how to pass these creds to clone repo. My Jenkinsfile would be like this-

```
pipeline {
agent any
environment {
      HOME_DIR = "$WORKSPACE/"
      }
stages {
stage('clone repos') {
  steps {
    **sh 'git clone http://<repo_url> '**
  }
}
}
```

I need to pass my creds to clone the repo. Does anyone has any idea about passing creds?? any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a credential with your git username and password. then use the credential id in the Jenkins file.

**Steps**

Click the Credentials link in the sidebar

Click on the Global credentials domain

Click [**Add Credential**]

Select a credential kind that can be used from your build jobs.

Username with password - a username/password pair

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
stage('clone repos') {
  steps {

   dir ("example"){                 
        git branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'your_credential_id', url: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/examples.git'

    }
  }
}
}
```